# WebDriver - Does the ":nth-of-type()" Selector work for IE 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

SeleniumHQ says that each driver supports whatever CSS Selectors its browser supports. According to [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), IE 9 should support the **:nth-of-type()** selector. However, I appear to be getting a `NullPointerException` from the depths of the `RemoteWebDriver` class when I execute `findElements` on this selector. My `By.cssSelector` looks like this:

```
table#ucsp_dgMultiSelect tr:nth-of-type(2) input#cbPres
```

This works fine on Chrome. Maybe IE 9 has a problem with putting that selector in the middle there, I don't know, but that would break a lot of my code. The **:nth-of-type()** selector has become my go-to for identifying WebElement locators within a table. Has anyone else had success using the **:nth-of-type()** selector as a locator with WebDriver and IE 9?

I'm using **IEDriverServer.exe.2.25.2.0** and my IE version is **9.0.8112.16421 64-bit**

Comment: Something seems wrong there. IE9 does support `:nth-of-type()` in CSS. Anyway, what if you used `:nth-child()` instead? For `tr` elements they're basically the same.

Comment: So long as you don't have some pesky `colgroup` or `caption` without a `thead` or `tbody`.

Comment: @canon: That will only matter in XML-serialized markup where `table > tr` elements in markup don't get assigned their own `tbody` in the DOM. In HTML, `tr:nth-child(n)` and `tr:nth-of-type(n)` is always the same for any `n`.

Comment: @canon: Unless WebDriver uses an XML parser...

Comment: Yes it does support it. See http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @Spudley: It's linked in the question ;)

Comment: @BoltClock - heh, I completely missed that.  :-D  Not sure how. Anyway, given that IE9 definitely does support it, I would guess it's more likely to be a problem in the Webdriver driver for IE than in IE itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDriver does, in fact, support the CSS selectors that the browser does, and if IE9 supports the `:nth-of-type()` selector, then so should the IE driver. However, that's not the entirety of the story. If the `DOCTYPE` in your page is not a modern standard (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html>`, IE also tries to guess at how it's supposed to render the document, and if it guesses that it should be rendering it as a previous IE version, it'll use the CSS selector engine of that previous version.

Since you're using IE9, there's a very easy way to see if WebDriver should be able to find the element with the selector you're trying to use. Open the "F12 Developer Tools" by hitting the function key F12 while you're on the page you're interested in. Go to the Script tab in the Developer tools, and type

```
document.querySelector('table#ucsp_dgMultiSelect tr:nth-of-type(2) input#cbPres')
```

If the console displays the element information, then WebDriver should be able to find it. If not, then IE can't find it, and WebDriver never will either.

This debugging technique will work anytime you're trying to find an element using CSS selectors in IE9, and is invaluable in helping find out if the problem is IE or if it's the driver. Additionally, the F12 Developer Tools also will tell you what mode IE is trying to render the page in, which can also be instructive.

Comment: Thanks very much! My company's site is supposed to be compatible with IE9 standards, but this page, and possibly others, are using Quirks Mode. If I change the document mode to IE9 Standards in the developer tools, the `querySelector` command succeeds. So I've found a bug, and can now go about making sure that our site has proper Doctypes. Thanks again!